# Disable drawing items on QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt

I have two QGraphicsView and one QGraphicsScene. One of views don't need to draw qraphicsitems. Is there any way to disable drawing of items on the view?

Answer (score 0):

From the Qt5.2 [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#updatesEnabled-prop):

> updatesEnabled : bool
>
> This property holds whether updates are enabled.
>
> An updates enabled widget receives paint events and has a system background; a disabled widget does not. This also implies that calling update() and repaint() has no effect if updates are disabled.

You'll probably have to show some code.  There are quite a few ways to do this but it's really based on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So one of the most simple ways to not draw items - set flag QGraphicsView::IndirectPaint for graphics view and overload drawItems methods in scene and view. Works for me.